# What is a good way to encrypt data in order to retrieve it back by 2 seperate parties

Tags: c#, encryption

I have searched StackOverflow and have found numerous questions where people do not recommend 2 way encryption but I have a situation I need to solve :

I take some non-payment related sensitive information from clients which I have to save in a SQL Server DB.

Now a simple solution would be to encrypt it using Salts + Hashes etc...

My issue is that I need that sensitive info in plain text later for legal purposes (Tax purposes, Legalities etc.) for the administration department.

Also, the sensitive info should be available to the user in plain text when required by the user.

But it needs to be decrypted for the administration team too.

How would I achieve the above ?

I am using C# for my back-end.

**EDIT** : Changed Title

Comment: Encrypt it? Preferably with a strong algorithm. Reversible encryption is a terrible idea for passwords, but obviously needed for other kinds of data. What exactly are you asking here; how to use the .NET encryption libraries (ton's of examples out there if that's the case)?

Comment: You should ensure you are using the correct terminology to help people understand and answer your question:

* Encryption - protecting data in a *reversible* way requiring *secret* information (i.e. a key)
* Hashing - protecting data in a *non-reversible* way which may or may not require secret information
* Encoding - converting data to a different format in a *reversible* way which does not require secret information

"2 way encryption" isn't a standard term, as encryption by definition is reversible. What you have seen people recommend is securely hashing passwords so they are not ...

Comment: ... recoverable in the event of datastore leaks. If you need to recover the data in plaintext later for requirements, you will need to use encryption. You will want to use symmetric encryption, such as AES with CBC/CTR/GCM block cipher mode of operation. In C#, `RijndaelManaged` is the class you will need to use.

Comment: @Andy IIRC RijandelManaged is deprecated in favor of AesManaged.

Comment: Good call. Not a C# developer so I think the deprecation could be made clearer on the doc pages.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Are you sure?  Rijndael and AES, while similar, aren't the same thing.  I can't see anywhere that `RijndaelManaged` is deprecated.  Can you link?

Comment: @LukePark Buried in the Remarks section of [MSDN - RijndaelManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx) is "The Rijndael class is the predecessor of the Aes algorithm. You should use the Aes algorithm instead of Rijndael." `Aes` is an abstract class and [`AesManaged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) is the concrete implementation.

Comment: @Andy That in no way suggests that Rijndael is "deprecated".  AES is just a subset of Rijndael.  Also, that page is for the abstract Rijndael class and not the implementation.  In most cases, yes, AES is the way to go, but if you know what you are doing, Rijndael is fine to use.  The problem, and likely the reason for that message, is that most people **don't** know what they are doing.

Comment: True. If someone has strong opinions on block size and feedback modes, they are welcome to use `RijndaelManaged`. Perhaps "not-recommended" is a better term than "deprecated".

Comment: @Andy Agreed.  I agree that AES is the best choice in nearly every situation.  I'm just being pedantic!

Comment: @Travis Don't change the title of the question. You have a new question, and so you should ask a new question. The history here serves to answer new people who come along with the same or similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) for using the `AesManaged` class to perform symmetric encryption and decryption. Perform the encryption before persisting in the database and decryption upon retrieval in authorized sessions.

I recommend using an authenticated encryption (AE or AEAD) mode to ensure message integrity and authentication. Always remember to use a unique and non-predictable IV for every message encrypted with the same key.

You may want to encrypt the sensitive data with two different keys -- one key for the user account so the user can see the data when logged in, and another for tax/audit personnel which is kept in a key escrow system so there is an auditable trail to see who is accessing the data. Both keys should be properly protected (i.e. not just policy but technical restrictions like dual key control or HSMs).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that C# has no built-in AE modes.  Theres [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) or the OP could use an [HMAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Andy - When you say 2 different keys, does that mean I will have to store 2 different encrypted versions of the data?

Comment: Yes, if you enforce complete isolation. You could technically encrypt the data with only one key and then encrypt that "session key" with two different master keys (i.e. one for the user and one for the legal team), but you would lose provability that the appropriate actor used the appropriate key.